# How do I retrieve a DocumentDB id when querying with the MongoDB API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

EDIT: we have just heard back from Microsoft that using the mongodb api against a "traditional" documentdb instance isn't supported.  I'll leave this question open until someone comes up with a custom solution or Microsoft enhances the product.

We have successfully connected to our existing DocumentDB instance using the mongodb API, but the `find()` method does not return the `id` field inside the results.

The examples on the [Query Tutorials page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-mongodb) show an `id` field being returned, but they also show an `"_id": "ObjectId(\"58f65e1198f3a12c7090e68c\")"` field appended with no explanation as to how that `58f6...` string is generated (it doesn't appear anywhere in the sample document at the top of the page).

For example, we can find this document using the query `find({"type":"attribute", "association.Season":"Spring"})`:

```
{
  "id": "ATTR-TEST-ATT-00007",
  "type": "attribute",
  "name": "Spring Football",
  "association": {
    "Season": "Spring"
  }
}
```

...but the mongodb API leaves out the id property from the document, so all we see is:

```
{
  "type": "attribute",
  "name": "Spring Football",
  "association": {
    "Season": "Spring"
  }
}
```

Also, if we use `find({"id": "ATTR-TEST-ATT-00001"})` nothing gets returned even though there is a document with that id in the database.

We have tried using the `project` argument to force inclusion of the id field, but it didn't work.

If we add an `_id` field to the document then the mongodb driver returns the _id field without needing a projection, but this is not a solution as we want to use both the DocumentDB SQL API and the mongodb API at the same time.

```
{
  "id": "ATTR-TEST-ATT-00007",
  "_id": "ATTR-TEST-ATT-00007",
  "type": "attribute",
  "name": "Spring Football",
  "association": {
    "Season": "Spring"
  }
}
```

How do we get the mongodb API to return the document's `id` field in queries?

Comment: Interoperability of SQL API and MongoDB API is not expected any time soon. Not sure why you want to use both of them really. What does SQL API have that MongoDB API doesn't?

Comment: Please read my question again to find the answers to your questions.